# Create many sourceSets in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, pmd

I have a project in which there are folder with different zip archives. I want to extract them and for each to make some checks. But want reports to be separated. For example *pmd check.*
So to be separated files  from each zip file has to be but in different sourseSets and when call

```
gradle check
```

For each of the dirs to generate reports with the checks.

Input files:
**sources1.zip,sources2.zip,sources3.zip,sources4.zip**
Each of the zip contains separate project.
for example:

```
src/main/java/sources1/Example.java
src/main/java/sources2/App.java
```

....
When run checks to be generated

```
build/reports/pmd/sources1SourceSet.html
build/reports/pmd/sources2SourceSet.html
build/reports/pmd/sources3SourceSet.html
build/reports/pmd/sources4SourceSet.html
```

So I want to declare this different sourceSets according the name of the zips and not to do it manually, but don't know how.

```
sourceSets {
    sourcest1{
        java {
            srcDirs  file("...")
        }
    }
}
```

Is there are another easy way to separated checks without creating new sourceSets for each zip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to start you could create dedicated tasks for each zip. This can be done in a loop:

```
["source1", "source2", "source3"].each{ sourceName ->
    tasks.create("pmd${sourceName}", Pmd){
        reports.html.reportsDir = "$buildDir/reports/pmd${sourceName}"

        source = zipTree("file/to/$sourceName.zip")
        ...
    }
}
```

cheers

Comment: Brilliant. But 
 reports.html.reportsDir = "$buildDir..."
makes Gradle to throw deprecation warning <b>Deprecated dynamic property: "reportsDir" on "Report html",value: "..."
Deprecated dynamic property "reportsDir" created in multiple locations.</b>

Comment: sorry my fault, use "reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/pmd${sourceName}") instead to get rid of the deprecation message